# How to apply in many hypothesis at once?

Tags: coq

I have these things as truth:

```
a, x, y : nat
l : list nat
H : x <= y
S : sorted (y :: l)
IHS : sorted (insert a (y :: l))
H0 : a > x
H1 : a > y
```

How may I apply `Nat.lt_le_incl` in both H0 and H1 without copy-paste? `apply in *` does not work, even if i `try` it. I get the following error:
`Syntax error: [id_or_meta] expected after 'in' (in [in_hyp_as])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `match` tactic:

```
repeat match goal with
| H : ?a > ?b |- _ => apply Nat.lt_le_incl in H
end
```

The `repeat` tactic simply runs its argument for as many times as possible.  The `match` tactic checks if the goal and context have a certain form and, if so, runs the tactic supplied in the corresponding branch.  (The wildcard after the `|-` means that we don't care what the goal is; we are just interested in finding hypotheses of the form `?a > ?b`.)